# Open a second usercontrol from the first user control wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application with MVVM pattern. I have a Main window with a few tabs. On clicking different buttons in the main window, it's user control will show up. I have that working fine. However, I need to open a user control when a button is clicked in one of the usercontrols. Not from the Main Window. How do I do this? 
This is what I have so far:

MainWindow.XAML : I am creating data templates for each user control

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type homeViewModel:HomeWindowViewModel}">
    <homeViewModel:HomeWindow></homeViewModel:HomeWindow>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:PauseViewModel}">
    <viewModel:Pause></viewModel:Pause>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type logoffVM:LogOffViewModel}">
    <logoffVM:LogOff></logoffVM:LogOff>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ReportViewModel}">
    <viewModel:Report></viewModel:Report>
</DataTemplate>
```

And have the usercontrols showing up inside ItemsControl:

```
<Grid x:Name="UserControlGrid"  Width="Auto" Height="auto" Margin="100,40,0,0">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewsToShow}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True" Width="auto" Height="auto"></Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I have the buttons bound to a Command in the MainWindow ViewModel class.

In the MainWindowViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableObject> ViewsToShow
{
    get
    {
        return viewsToShow;
    }
    set
    {
        viewsToShow = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ViewsToShow");
    }
}
```

The Commands :

```
public ICommand GetNextCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(() => GetNext()); }
}

public ICommand GetOrderCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(() => GetOrder()); }
}
```

And the Methods that load usercontrols:

```
public void GetNext()
{
    Order orders = new Order();
    ViewsToShow.Clear();
    ViewsToShow.Add(new OrderDisplayViewModel("GetNext", orders, new WindowFactory()));
}

public void GetOrder()
{
    ViewsToShow.Clear();
    ViewsToShow.Add(new GetOrderViewModel());
}
```

All this is working fine from the MainWindow. But how do I open the GetOrder user control from the GetNext user control?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to a property of the parent window's `DataContext` from a `UserControl` using a `RelativeSource`;

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.GetOrderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you @mm8.. I'm fairy new to MVVM..  where should I have this piece of code, that binds the RelativeSource? In the MainWindow Button?

Comment: @UUser: The `Button` goes in the `UserControl`.

Comment: Thank you, so what do I do after adding this button? Should I do anything else to open the second usercontrol?

Comment: @UUser: Clicking on the button should then invoke the `GetOrderCommand` of the `MainWindowViewModel`. Of course you need to write some code that actually does that you want in the `Execute` method of the command. But this should be the same as before.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Writing here to say thank you so much @mm8. I have been trying to find how to do this for a long time and I couldn't find an answer. Why was It so hard to find the solution? Is that something that we shouldn't do? Displaying another usercontrol for a usercontrol?